# Spoiler messages in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a bot in discord.py, and I'm getting to the stage of making more complex commands and making my easier commands better and more flexible.

My most recent endeavor is my */say* command. I'm making it able to do tts message and spoilers, but I can't find anything on the latter. Is it as simple as the tts or is it more complex?

Comment: You can use it like this to spoiler a message ||<message>|| .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark your text as spoiler by putting <||||> around it. Example: `”<||hi||>”`